# Can I use the JMeter result of Json Path Expression in Json Regex Extractor to extract only a part of the result?

Tags: jmeter, post-processing, json-path-expression

The Json Path Expression returns something like: `"folder/subfolder/123456".`

I only need the "123456", is it possible to extraxt that with the regular Expression extractor based on the result of the Json Path Extractor?

Or another way would be awesome too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this `folder/subfolder/123456` stored in a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) called i.e. `someVariable`

[image]

you can extract the numeric part as follows:

[image]

Demo:

[image]

Just make sure to put the Regular Expression Extractor **below** the JSON Extractor as the Post-Processors are being executed upside down and the JSON Extractor needs to be first

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: You absolute **Legend**!